# Deleting/Updating RavenDB document via command without change vector

Tags: ravendb

I have a entity which I want to delete/update in RavenDB, but it is not associated with any Session. AFAIK there are two ways to accomplish this. I go with an example for delete, but it should be the same with put I think.

Way of the Load:

```csharp
var trackedEntity = await this.asyncSession.LoadAsync<MyEntity>(untrackedEntity.Id, cancellationToken);
session.Delete(trackedEntity);
```

Way of the Command:

```
var command = new DeleteDocumentCommand(untrackedEntity.Id, null);
await session.Advanced.RequestExecutor.ExecuteAsync(command, session.Advanced.Context);
```

With the load you need to do an additional trip to RavenDB to get the entity and track it by the session.
With the command you do not need the additional trip, but you do not have the change vector for concurrency control.

I would say the way of the load is safer and slower, the way of the command is quicker, but you could run into concurrency issues.

Is the last assumption correct?
How likely is it to run into concurrency issues with the command?
Can a general statement be made which way is preferable?